# Select values from Three tables value not in another table MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Database. I am having three tables like T1,T2,T3. I want to get a column values from a table by excluding the values exists in another table.
SELECT T3 THEN
SELECT T2 NOT in T3   THEN
SELECT T1 NOT in T3 and T2

```
CREATE TABLE T1(CID INT,NAME VARCHAR(100),EMAIL VARCHAR(50), MOIBLE VARCHAR(20)) 
CREATE TABLE T2(CID INT,NAME VARCHAR(100),EMAIL VARCHAR(50), MOIBLE VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE T3(CID INT,NAME VARCHAR(100),EMAIL VARCHAR(50), MOIBLE VARCHAR(20))
```

Insert value

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,'TEST1','a@gmail','123456')
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2,'TEST2','b@gmail','123456')
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3,'TEST3','c@gmail','123456')
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (4,'TEST4','d@gmail','123456')

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1,'TEST1','updateda@gmail','123456')
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2,'TEST2','updatedb@gmail','77777')

INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (1,'TEST1','updateda@gmail','999999')
```

Expected output

SELECT T3 and

SELECT T2 record NOT in T3 and

SELECT T1 record NOT in T3 and T2

```
cid   Name    email             moible
 1    TEST1   updateda@gmail    999999     From T3
 2    TEST2   updatedb@gmail    77777      From T2
 3    TEST3   c@gmail           123456     From T1
 4    TEST4   d@gmail           123456     From T1
```

I have written query for this

```
SELECT *  FROM T2 where cid not in ( SELECT cid from T3)
UNION
SELECT * FROM T3
```

Here How to include T1 table?

Comment: Are you trying to get a `UNION` of the values contained in that column across all three tables?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `NOT IN` or `EXIST EXISTS`? `EXCEPT`? With no sample data, no expected results, and no attempts, this is impossible for us to answer.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add anther 1 union cid not in T2 and T3

```
SELECT * from T1 where cid not in(SELECT cid  FROM T2 where cid not in ( SELECT 
      cid from T3)
      UNION
       SELECT cid FROM T3)
 UNION
 SELECT *  FROM T2 where cid not in ( SELECT cid from T3)
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM T3
```